# GAE Task queue is keeping negative tasks running in the "Tasks Running" section in the admin console

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I am currently working on a Python project with GAE, and as strange as it may seem, my default queue is keeping a negative count of tasks running even though i manually deleted all tasks. Why is it doing this odd thing? and how to stop it? attached you can find a picture of what i mean...

[image]

And due to this issue, my scheduled cron jobs are not running when using the default queue, i have not tested it with a custom queue. But a negative count of tasks running? seriously??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an AppEngine issue, it was fixed later that day.